# Embed desktop application into Windows 8 app

Tags: windows-8, desktop-application, windows-store-apps

I'm afraid I know the answer but hope to overlook something. Is it possible to embed a desktop application into a Windows 8 app?

I would say it cannot be possible because an app should also run under the ARM architecture and desktop applications can't run there but hope, that someone can imagine a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  That is not possible.  Not just because of differences in processor architectures, but also because of a vastly different security and runtime environment.  Lots of other reasons as well, but no need to go into it. :)

Answer (score 3):

## **NO**

Not just because of ARM architecture as you can also target x86 or x64 with windows store apps but because of differences between api and restrictions. The WinRT/Windows store applications run in a sandbox and doesn't have access to critical system features/api's. You can embed a desktop app into windows store app but it won't do anything. You won't be able to install it or use it. Also if you plan to upload the application to the Windows 8 store than it won't get approved.

Although you can provide a link to users in your application by with they can download and install desktop application, and that'll all you can really do.